# Use custom status code or render custom text for ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http

which is a better approach? a custom status code or render a text for ajax

```
render :text => "pusher"
```

or

```
render :nothing => true , :status => 900
```

for

```
$.ajax({
  success : function(d , s , r){
    if (d == "pusher"){
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to indicate success then you **must** return a [2XX status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) or you're not speaking HTTP. If you're not return a valid status code then you can't expect the clients do anything useful with your response.

So you have to return one of the 2XX status codes so you're left with:

```
render :text => 'pusher'
```

as your only viable solution.

Answer (score 1):

best practice is to use http status for these kind of stuff.

But it will only work with the http state code.
So if you have a response related to business logic and not to 2xx or 4xx status, you will need your `render :text => "pusher"` approch (as "pusher" is not an http state).

In my apps, I prefer write an API and link some standart response to my business logic.